# My function in Octave doesn't work

Tags: function, octave

I'm working with Octave4.2.1 and I have written this function (in the file `OctaveFunction.m`):

```
    function y = squareNumber(x)
      y = x^2;
    endfunction
```

but if I call the function, I get this error:

> `error: 'squareNumber' undefined near line 1 column 1`

and if I try to call the function in this way:

```
OctaveFunction squareNumber(4)
```

I get another error:

> `warning: function name 'squareNumber' does not agree with function filename 'C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\OctaveFunction.m'
>   error: for x^A, A must be a square matrix.  Use .^ for elementwise power.
>   error: called from
>       OctaveFunction at line 2 column 7`

Where did I go wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Try `y = x.^2;` as the error suggests

Comment: An alternative solution is to not start your file with the function (ex a var assignment). If your file starts with a function, the function should have the same name as the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your file name does not match the function name. If you were to match these, this should resolve your first error.

---

Regarding the elementwise power error: If given the proper input (4) this should not lead to an error, as 4 is obviously a square matrix.

Hence it seems that some undesired input is fed to your function, but again this problem is likely to disappear if you rename the file to match the functionname, and call the function as usual. (so without OctaveFunction).

Answer (score 1):

You Must rename your file such as your function name
for example: your file name is (main.m) and your function name is (main)

Comment: That's what the accepted answer said several years ago.